# QTableView animate row hiding

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

`hideRow()` makes row disappear immediately, I want smooth transition, some fade effect.

Is that possible? I couldn't find any reference in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably get by using [`QTableView::setRowHeight`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setRowHeight) and a `QTimer`.

```
/*
 * Get QTableView pointer and index of the row to hide from
 * somewhere.
 */
QTableView *tv = ...;
int row = ...;

/*
 * Create a timer.  It will be deleted by our lambda when no
 * longer needed so no memory leak.
 */
auto *timer = new QTimer;

/*
 * Connect the timer's timeout signal to a lambda that will
 * do the work.
 */
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout,
        [=]()
        {
          int height = tv->rowHeight(row);
          if (height == 0) {

            /*
             * If the row height is already zero then hide the
             * row and delete the timer.
             */
            tv->setRowHidden(row, true);
            timer->deleteLater();
          } else {

            /*
             * Otherwise, decrease the height of the row by a
             * suitable amount -- 1 pixel in this case.
             */
            tv->setRowHeight(row, height - 1);
          }
        });

/*
 * Start the timer running at 10Hz.
 */
timer->start(100);
```

Note that the above code is untested.  Also, rather than creating an 'ethereal' `QTimer` you might want to make it a member variable of your view class or whatever.

Comment: I had the same idea, but I thought there might be some more convenient way. I will test this and report back. Thank you

Comment: It works. Although the whole thing looks like a hack. I would like to use proper animation framework but... it is what it is.